# Drupal 8 path token in views

Tags: drupal

Во вьюшке в "rewrite results" хочу обернуть поля ссылкой, только не могу получить [path] как это сделать в drupal 8 ?

```
<a href="[path]"> 
  {{ field_image  }}
  {{ title }}
  {{ field_preview }}
</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно скрыть все поля из вывода и добавить поле "*Сcылка на content*".

В нем сделайте "*перезаписать результаты*", тег `<a>` добавлять уже не нужно, содержимое этого поля обертывается ссылкой.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]